# Option insertion problem in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

```
var spaces="----";  
var category_name="category";
    var category_text=spaces+category_name;
    alert(category_text);
    $('select').append($("<option>").attr({'value' : inserted_id , 'label' : category_name}).text(category_text));
```

This code includes option to my listbox.

**The problem in Internet Explorer 7**. The option is included, but the expected display is `'----category'`. But Internet Explorer 7 displays only `category` in options. Since I am using tree order I need to have hyphens before some category. How can I solve it in Internet Explorer 7?

Comment: If your tree is only two levels, why not use `<optgroup>`s for the 'category' headings?

Comment: Its a multi level tree. My question is why ie7 neglects hypens

Comment: @karim Your answer worked for me post it again with label i inserted option. it works in ie7. Thanks. Post it again to select ur answer as correct

Comment: have you tried &#45; instead of -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select')
    .append($("<option />")
        .attr({'value' : inserted_id , 
               'label' : category_name, 
               'text' : category_text
             }));
```

or this:

```
$('select')
    .append($("<option />")
        .attr({'value' : inserted_id , 
               'label' : category_text 
             }));
```

Comment: Refer this http://thedailyreviewer.com/windowsnet/view/hyphen-problem-in-ie-101397871 I think it is impossible to add hypens to display in ie7

Answer (score 0):

You set label to category_name.
It seems like if you set the lable it displays this instead of the inner HTML.

Comment: Your solution is not apt i need to change label declaration from 'category_name' to 'category_text'